# Optimization of nonlinear equation

Tags: equation-solving

I m try to solve non linear equations, and I m blocked

```
E1 = 0.53*10^9
k1 = 0.269*10^(-6)
K1 = 0.5
[Alpha]1 = 30*10^(-6)
[Nu]1 = 0.25
[Mu]1 = E1/(2 (1 + \[Nu]1))

E2 = 125*10^9
k2 = 12.98*10^(-6)
K2 = 54
[Alpha]2 = 12*10^(-6)
[Nu]2 = 0.5
[Mu]2 = E2/(2 (1 + \[Nu]2))
k = k1/k2
K = K1/K2
[Alpha] = \[Alpha]1 (1 + \[Nu]1)/(\[Alpha]2 (1 + \[Nu]2))
f = 0.4
\[Xi]1[c1_] = Sqrt[0.5 (1 + Sqrt[1 + (c1/k)^2])]
\[Xi]2[c2_] = Sqrt[0.5 (1 + Sqrt[1 + (c2)^2])]
\[Eta]1[c1_] = Sqrt[0.5 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + (c1/k)^2])]
\[Eta]2[c2_] = Sqrt[0.5 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + c2^2])]
H1sym[A_] = 2*\[Mu]2*\[Mu]1*k2*\[Alpha]2 (1 + \[Nu]2)/(K2 (\[Mu]2 (1 - \[Nu]1) (A Sech[A]^2 +Tanh[A]) + \[Mu]1 (1 - \[Nu]2) Tanh[A]^2))         
     
H2sym[A_] = 4*\[Mu]2*\[Mu]1* k2*\[Alpha]2 (1 + \[Nu]2)/(K2 (\[Mu]2 (1 - 2 \[Nu]1) (A Sech[A]^2 +Tanh[A]) - \[Mu]1 (1 - 2 \[Nu]2) Tanh[A] + \[Mu]1 A Sech[A]^2))

Hsym[A_] = H1sym[A]/H2sym[A]

I1[c2_, A_] = (\[Xi]2[c2] Sinh[2 A \[Xi]2[c2]] - \[Eta]2[c2] Sin[2 A \[Eta]2[c2]])/(Cosh[2 A \[Xi]2[c2]] + Cos[2 A \[Eta]2[c2]])
I2[c2_, A_] = (\[Xi]2[c2] Sin[2 A \[Eta]2[c2]] + \[Eta]2[c2] Sinh[2 A \[Xi]2[c2]])/(Cosh[2 A \[Xi]2[c2]] + Cos[2 A \[Eta]2[c2]])
I3[c1_, A_] = \[Alpha]/\[Xi]1[c1] (A Sech[A]^2 + Tanh[A])
I4[c2_, A_] = Tanh[A]/(\[Xi]2[c2] \[Eta]2[c2]) I2[c2, A]
J3[c1_, A_] = \[Alpha] \[Eta]1[c1]/(\[Xi]1[c1] (\[Xi]1[c1] + 1)) (A Sech[A]^2 + Tanh[A])
J4[c2_, A_] = Tanh[A]/(\[Xi]2[c2] \[Eta]2[c2]) (\[Xi]2[c2] Sinh[2 A \[Xi]2[c2]] - \[Eta]2[c2] Sin[2 A \[Eta]2[c2]] - Tanh[A] (Cosh[2 A \[Xi]2[c2]] + Cos[2 A \[Eta]2[c2]]))/(Cosh[2 A \[Xi]2[c2]] + Cos[2 A [Eta]2[c2]])


V[c1_, c2_] = c1 - c2

equation68[c1_, c2_, A_] = K \[Xi]1[c1] + I1[c2, A] + f Hsym[A] (K \[Eta]1[c1] + I2[c2, A]) - f H1sym[A]/2 (I3[c1, A] + I4[c2, A]) (V[c1, c2])

equation69[c1_, c2_, A_] = K \[Eta]1[c1] + I2[c2, A] - f Hsym[A] (k \[Xi]1[c1] + I1[c2, A]) + f Hsym[A]/2 (J3[c1, A] + J4[c2, A]) (V[c1, c2])
```

I want to plot V in function of A, how can I tell Mathematica to do this?
I try to solve the system to found c1 and c2 in function of A, but it was not working,

Thank you

Comment: Regarding the function V it should be written as  V[c1_,c2_]:= c1-c2 and can be plotted with Plot3D[V[x,y],{x,0,1},{y,0,1}] without problem. Your text suffers from some minor flaws.

Comment: Thank, I will try to revised the minor flaws.
But for the 3DPlot, it's not what I need. I need to solve equation68 and equation69 in order to have a 2D plot of V in function of A

Comment: @ValentinBRUANT In what range you try to plot `V[A]`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  between 10^(-2) to 10^(4)

Comment: @ValentinBRUANT Can we put `equation68==0, equation69==0` to find `c1,c2`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes.

Comment: @ValentinBRUANT Then see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After minor modification of code we have

```
E1 = 0.53*10^9;
k1 = 0.269*10^(-6);
K1 = 0.5;
\[Alpha]1 = 30*10^(-6);
\[Nu]1 = 0.25;
\[Mu]1 = E1/(2 (1 + \[Nu]1));

E2 = 125*10^9;
k2 = 12.98*10^(-6);
K2 = 54;
\[Alpha]2 = 12*10^(-6);
\[Nu]2 = 0.5;
\[Mu]2 = E2/(2 (1 + \[Nu]2));
k = k1/k2;
K = K1/K2;
\[Alpha] = \[Alpha]1 (1 + \[Nu]1)/(\[Alpha]2 (1 + \[Nu]2));
f = 0.4;
\[Xi]1[c1_] := Sqrt[0.5 (1 + Sqrt[1 + (c1/k)^2])];
\[Xi]2[c2_] := Sqrt[0.5 (1 + Sqrt[1 + (c2)^2])];
\[Eta]1[c1_] := Sqrt[0.5 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + (c1/k)^2])];
\[Eta]2[c2_] := Sqrt[0.5 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + c2^2])];
H1sym[A_] := 
  2*\[Mu]2*\[Mu]1*
   k2*\[Alpha]2 (1 + \[Nu]2)/(K2 (\[Mu]2 (1 - \[Nu]1) (A Sech[A]^2 + 
           Tanh[A]) + \[Mu]1 (1 - \[Nu]2) Tanh[A]^2));

H2sym[A_] := 
  4*\[Mu]2*\[Mu]1*
   k2*\[Alpha]2 (1 + \[Nu]2)/(K2 (\[Mu]2 (1 - 2 \[Nu]1) (A Sech[A]^2 +
            Tanh[A]) - \[Mu]1 (1 - 2 \[Nu]2) Tanh[
          A] + \[Mu]1 A Sech[A]^2));

Hsym[A_] := H1sym[A]/H2sym[A];

I1[c2_, A_] := (\[Xi]2[c2] Sinh[2 A \[Xi]2[c2]] - \[Eta]2[c2] Sin[
       2 A \[Eta]2[c2]])/(Cosh[2 A \[Xi]2[c2]] + Cos[2 A \[Eta]2[c2]]);
I2[c2_, A_] := (\[Xi]2[c2] Sin[2 A \[Eta]2[c2]] + \[Eta]2[c2] Sinh[
       2 A \[Xi]2[c2]])/(Cosh[2 A \[Xi]2[c2]] + Cos[2 A \[Eta]2[c2]]);
I3[c1_, A_] := \[Alpha]/\[Xi]1[c1] (A Sech[A]^2 + Tanh[A]);
I4[c2_, A_] := Tanh[A]/(\[Xi]2[c2] \[Eta]2[c2]) I2[c2, A];
J3[c1_, A_] := \[Alpha] \[Eta]1[
     c1]/(\[Xi]1[c1] (\[Xi]1[c1] + 1)) (A Sech[A]^2 + Tanh[A]);
J4[c2_, A_] := 
  Tanh[A]/(\[Xi]2[c2] \[Eta]2[
       c2]) (\[Xi]2[c2] Sinh[2 A \[Xi]2[c2]] - \[Eta]2[c2] Sin[
        2 A \[Eta]2[c2]] - 
      Tanh[A] (Cosh[2 A \[Xi]2[c2]] + Cos[2 A \[Eta]2[c2]]))/(Cosh[
       2 A \[Xi]2[c2]] + Cos[2 A \[Eta]2[c2]]);


V[c1_, c2_] := c1 - c2;

equation68[c1_, c2_, A_] := 
  K \[Xi]1[c1] + I1[c2, A] + f Hsym[A] (K \[Eta]1[c1] + I2[c2, A]) - 
    f H1sym[A]/2 (I3[c1, A] + I4[c2, A])*(V[c1, c2]) == 0;

equation69[c1_, c2_, A_] := 
  K \[Eta]1[c1] + I2[c2, A] - f Hsym[A] (k \[Xi]1[c1] + I1[c2, A]) + 
    f Hsym[A]/2 (J3[c1, A] + J4[c2, A])*(V[c1, c2]) == 0;

sol[A_] := 
 FindRoot[{equation68[c1, c2, A], 
    equation69[c1, c2, A]}, {{c1, 1/10}, {c2, 1/10}}, 
   MaxIterations -> 10000] // Quiet
```

Now we can calculate function `V[c1,c2]` for every `A` as `V[c1,c2]/.sol[A]`. But result is not stable. So we can plot `V[A]` as illustration, and not as finale result at small and medium scale

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{A, V[c1, c2] /. sol[A]}, {A, .01, 1, .01}]]

ListLinePlot[Table[{A, V[c1, c2] /. sol[A]}, {A, 1.1, 10, .1}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure1]

Comment: tanks a lot. I may know why the resultat is not stable and try to fix that on my side.